# onclick button replace buttons places

Tags: android, button, random, action, coordinate

I created a game which has 6 buttons, the buttons supposed to change their places when you click button2, here is the script I did:

```
if (id == R.id.button2) {


            action1();
            action2();
            action3();
            action4();
            action5();
            action6();

            }
```

and here is the actions:

```
private void action1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setX(50);
    int min = 0;
    int max = 200;
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    button1.setY(i1);
    }   
private void action2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setX(50);
    int min = 0;
    int max = 1200;
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    button2.setY(i1);       }  
private void action3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setX(50);
    int min = 400;
    int max = 600;
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    button3.setY(i1);       }  
private void action4() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setX(50);
    int min = 600;
    int max = 800;
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    button4.setY(i1);       }  
private void action5() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setX(50);
    int min = 800;
    int max = 1000;
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    button5.setY(i1);       }  
private void action6() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button6.setX(50);
    int min = 1000;
    int max = 1200;
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    button6.setY(i1);       
    }
```

My problem is: the buttons changing their places to one on the other and you can't press the buttons because of it, what can I do to fix this?

I thought about this option:

get the Y coordinate of the buttom and the top, divide by 6, and then I know what is the range of the Y coordinate I should give for each button, how can I do it? or can you tell me about a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code. First, You should reuse whatever resources you can reuse. In this case, you should store references to your Buttons and Random. Your numbers are always the same, so you may declare them as class variables. Lastly, you can solve your problems by remembering "occupied" positions.

P.S. don't forget that different screens have different resolutions.

Working code != good code. Also, there is programming guideline called DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. Your code is far from DRY. In general, if you copy your code several times - wrap it in method, rather than copy the body. Your 6 action methods could be written in 5 times less lines:

```
private void action(Button b, int min, int max){
    b.setX(50); 
    b.setY(r.nextInt(range));
}
```

Define Buttons and Random as class variables, so you can reuse them:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
Random rl
Button button1;
...
Button button6;
//List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>(); might be even better
```

onCreate:

```
r = new Random();
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
...
button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
```

And when you click them:

```
if(id==R.id.button2){
    action(button1,0,200);
    ...
}
```

To keep buttons separated, check if random value does not overlap with all buttons:

```
int getRandom(int min,int max){
    int val = r.nextInt(range);
    if(button1.getY()>val&&button1.getY()+width<val){
        //buttons overlap, try another random value
    } else {
        //check other buttons
    }
}
```

Comment: my code running fine, why does I have a problem? the numbers are not the same.. every button goes to an other place.. and the solution is - button 1 will set into place and the button2 will not be able to set in this place? how can i do it?

Comment: too hard to me :( my first app, errors..
in all the mentions of r : r cannot be resolved to a variable and at the line of "if(button1.getY()>val&&button1.getY()+width<val){ "
width cannot be resolved to a variable..

Comment: In that case, you should begin with some basic programming courses. Any language, though lower level or static typed would be better and harder.